# How can I translate several txt files saved in different folders?

Tags: file-transfer

I need to:

1) translate several txt (or pdf) files. They are saved in different folders in my notebook.

2) save the translated text in a new folder.

the best answer I could find on google in to use [soimort](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell), which translate a txt file.

Read on [soimort](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell):

> Translate a File
>
> Instead of using the -input option, a file URI scheme (file://
>   followed by the file name) can be used as a command-line argument:
>
> $ trans :fr file://input.txt

My question is: how can I do the previous task using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Do it one file at a time? Unless it is lots and lots of files, *looking* at what you are doing is crucial.

If they live in `dir1`, `dir2`, and so on:

```
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
   (cd $d; for f in `ls *.txt`; do frobnicate $f; done)
done
```

Explanation: The outer `for` walks over directories. In a subhell (the`(...)`) we enter the directory, grab the names of any `*.txt` files, `frobnicate` each of them in turn (the inner `for`), and we are `done`. As the inner job is in a subshell, we are back were we started, and can go to the next directory.

Careful, this will explode in your face if any directory or file name contains spaces or other funky characters. It doesn't save away the originals (in case `frobnicate` mangles their contents), and (obviously) will frobnicate any already frobnicated files it finds.

Comment: My file name contains spaces. Is there a way to solve this problem? What is the problem with spaces?